# Chrome NetLog event types

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I'm trying to time page rendering times using different network settings. For that I am looking at the NetLog created by Chrome (using the --log-net-log flag with --net-log-level=0). However, I'm having trouble understanding the created JSON log; it's mainly to do with matching event types. Take for example this event:

```
{"params":{"delta":-871,"stream_id":3,"window_size":10484889},"phase":0,"source":{"id":78,"type":1},"time":"1292588413","type":163}
```

According to net/base/net_log_event_type_list.h, no event type has such parameters. What am I missing here?

Answer (score -3):

NetLog can probably give you the data you want, but all of those events are specific to individual requests -- a modern page is composed of dozens of these, so you'll be way down in the weeds to piece it all together. Instead, what you're probably looking for is the NavTiming API!

A quick writeup on the API here:
http://www.igvita.com/2012/04/04/measuring-site-speed-with-navigation-timing/

That will give you detailed stats on all the components such as DNS, redirects, as well as DCL, and onload events amongst others.

Comment: Indeed, the NavTiming API is very handy. But what I want to do is to time the loading of different pages in Chrome under different network stack options so I need to script this externally without tampering with the pages.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.